# Adding new error code in SSLerrs.h

Tags: ssl

I am adding a new SSL specific error code inside SSLerrs.h in Mozilla NSS.

My question is, which file that contains the html page for that error? Because I need to modify the page too - to add my own messages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`/docshell/resources/content/netError.xhtml` is the generic UI for network errors, including SSL errors.

`/security/manager/locales/en-US/chrome/pipnss/nsserrors.properties` contains translations of `SSL_ERROR_*` to user-visible strings; see also other locales.